# El resultado de esta condición siempre es "cinco" pero no me deja realizar la iteración

Tags: javascript, condiciones, javascript-objeto, vanilla

estoy intentando realizar que me reconozca de que cuando coloque un botón en específico, el código lo que haga sea reconocer que botón coloqué y arroje según cada botón que coloque un resultado. Pero no me deja realizarlo.

El problema radica en que quiero llamar a que realice con el boton al dar click la accion de seleccionar según el tipo de "innerhtml" una accion, pero probando el codigo no me permite realizar eso, ya que la respuesta siempre que la coloco es cinco, dos veces. He intentando cambiar el foreach por un for, he intentando hasta no colocar un switch sino un for simple y no me funciona :(

Adjunto el codigo para dar a entender mi idea:

```
var inputValue = 0
var totalTip = 0;


const $inputBill = document.getElementsByClassName('bill_input')[0];
$inputBill.addEventListener('keyup', (event) => {
    const inputBill = event.path[0].value;
    inputValue =+ inputBill;    
})


const $five = document.querySelector('#five');
const $ten = document.querySelector('#ten');
const $fifteen = document.querySelector('#fifteen');
const $twentyFive = document.querySelector('#twentyFive');
const $fifty = document.querySelector('#fifty');

buttonsArray = [$five, $ten, $fifteen, $twentyFive, $fifty] ;

$five.addEventListener('click' , calculatorTip);
$ten.addEventListener('click' , calculatorTip);
$fifteen.addEventListener('click' , calculatorTip);
$twentyFive.addEventListener('click' , calculatorTip);
$fifty.addEventListener('click' , calculatorTip);



function calculatorTip () {
    buttonsArray.forEach(button => {
        switch (button.innerHTML) {
            case '5%':
                console.log('cinco por ciento')
                break;
            case '10%':
                console.log('diez por ciento')
                break;
            case '15%':
                console.log('quince por ciento')
                break;
            case '25%':
                console.log('veinticinco por ciento')
                break;
            case '50%':
                console.log('cincuenta por ciento')
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }     
    });
}
```

Comment: Saludos. Revisa tu implementación de **calculatorTip** te estas basando en el **buttonsArray** no estás (digamos) *identificando* el botón que es cliqueado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tal como te señalaba RobertoLeOr, el problema radica en que tu función no identifica el botón que está siendo clickado, sino que se ejecuta por igual para el `innerHTML` de cada uno de los elementos del `buttonsArray` (a fin de cuentas, eso significa `foreach` :P).

La solución sería, por lo tanto, leer sólo el `innerHTML` del elemento que haya sido clickado.

```js
const $five = document.querySelector('#five');
const $ten = document.querySelector('#ten');
const $fifteen = document.querySelector('#fifteen');
const $twentyFive = document.querySelector('#twentyFive');
const $fifty = document.querySelector('#fifty');

buttonsArray = [$five, $ten, $fifteen, $twentyFive, $fifty];

buttonsArray.forEach(button => button.addEventListener('click', function calculatorTip() {
  switch (button.innerHTML) {
    case '5%':
      console.log('cinco por ciento')
      break;
    case '10%':
      console.log('diez por ciento')
      break;
    case '15%':
      console.log('quince por ciento')
      break;
    case '25%':
      console.log('veinticinco por ciento')
      break;
    case '50%':
      console.log('cincuenta por ciento')
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }
}));
```

```html
<button id="five" type="button">5%</button>
<button id="ten" type="button">10%</button>
<button id="fifteen" type="button">15%</button>
<button id="twentyFive" type="button">25%</button>
<button id="fifty" type="button">50%</button>
```

Como ves, en este ejemplo el `innerHTML` que se lee es sólo el del `button` que está siendo clickado, no el de todos ellos. ;)

Comment: Muchas gracias compañeros, solucionado